# Re writting gradle code to be compatible with 5.1

Tags: java, hibernate, gradle

I am stuck on trying to re work some code to be compatible with gradle 5.1.  I am currently using 4.10.  The following block of code is for hibernate that I copied (for the most part) so honestly I am not 100% sure of what it all does, still fairly new to gradle.  Here is the following code

```
    doLast{
        ant.taskdef( resource:"org/aspectj/tools/ant/taskdefs/aspectjTaskdefs.properties", classpath: configurations.ajc.asPath)
        ant.iajc(
            source: sourceCompatibility,
            target: targetCompatibility,
            Xlint: "ignore",
            destDir: sourceSets.main.output.classesDir.absolutePath, 
            maxmem: "1024m",
            fork: "true",
            aspectPath: configurations.aspects.asPath,
            sourceRootCopyFilter: "**/.svn/*,**/*.java",
            classpath: configurations.compile.asPath
        ){
            sourceroots{
                sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs.each{
                    pathelement(location:it.absolutePath)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The code in question is the following line

```
destDir: sourceSets.main.output.classesDir.absolutePath,
```

as it throws the following error

> Could not get unknown property 'classesDir' for main classes of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSetOutput.

Changing the code to

```
destDir: sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs.absolutePath,
```

causes the following error

> No such property: absolutePath for class: org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection

So I am looking into alternatives (or syntax updates)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I fixed it by changing the following

```
destDir: "build/classes",
```

Everything seems to be working as expected

Answer (score 0):

For gradle 8.2 use the following:

```
sourceSets.main.java.classesDirectory.get()
```